# Generating a .dll from a cmake project for use in Unity

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, opencv, unity-game-engine

I've got a C++ project running in Visual Studio 15 that contains some OpenCV features. My goal is to execute methods from that project in a Unity project. I've had a look at writing native plugins and marshaling, and I got an almost empty C++ project built to a .dll and successfully used this in Unity to call a function of the library.

C#

```
public class Controller : MonoBehaviour {
    [DllImport("DllName")]
    private static extern int GetRandom();
    void Start () {
        print(GetRandom());
    }
}
```

C++

```
#include <iostream>
#define DllExport __declspec (dllexport)
extern "C" {
    DllExport int GetRandom() {
        return rand();
    }
}
```

results in the Unity log printing a random number, so the basics work.

My issue is that if I want to use OpenCV, I have to use Cmake (GUI) to generate a C++ project, from which I'm unable to build a .dll that I can use.

I already have the `Configuration Properties->General->Project Defaults->Configuration Type` set to .dll, but when building, it says `Project not selected to build for this solution configuration`.

I've read that I also have to Check "Deploy" in the Configuration Manager, but I think this isn't true, because in the OpenCV project, as well as in my little project that works, in both cases the "Deploy" column is greyed out and unchecked.

What do I have to do, to build the OpenCV project as .dll? Possibly it's some setting I in cmake, or maybe it's something inside Visual Studio, I guess.

Comment: "...if I want to use OpenCV, I have to use Cmake (GUI) to generate a C++ project..." -- Why? Could you show us your `CMakeLists.txt`? Or did you mean you don't normally use CMake to generate your MSVS solutions?

Comment: I have to build cmake from source to be able to use the contrib features that I need and for all the options to set the way I need them. I do use CMake regularly.

Comment: OK. So you use CMake for the above mentioned DLL as well? Is you issue only using OpenCV in that DLL (Which would mean setting appropriate include and library search paths, and specifying the OpenCV libraries to link with)? Or are you also trying to set it up so that OpenCV gets automatically built (if it doesn't exist) as part of your DLL solution? Or perhaps something else?

Comment: I have OpenCV set up and running in an application project. I now want that project's methods to be executed by Unity. To do so, I need to build that C++ application as a dynamic library from which I can call methods in C#, like shown above.
I used CMake to build OpenCV and I used CMake to build the project that uses OpenCV. The include dirs and such are set correctly, because it all works in Visual Studio as executable.
I assume that I have to convert that application project to a library project,  but I'm not sure how to do that and if that is even the best way.

Comment: I don't see a reason why you should be converting project. You already have some baseline DLL that you've shown above. Just add all the cpp/hpp files with the code you need to the DLL project as well. Set the includes/libraries on your DLL, link it with OpenCV. If you wanna do it nicer, then create an additional (static) library, and move the common bits there. Then you link your exe and dll with that new lib.

Comment: Assuming you use CMake to generate solution for your existing OpenCV, then either of those approaches I mentioned are basically adding a few lines to the `CMakeLists.txt`. It would be useful to show it.